# What is the smallest possible value of $P(A^\complement\cap B^\complement\cap C^\complement)$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

> Let $A$,$B$,$C$ be three events in a probability space. Suppose that 
>   \begin{align}
> \mathbb P(A) &= 0.5\\
> \mathbb P(B) &= 0.3\\
> \mathbb P(C) &= 0.2\\
> \mathbb P(A\cap B) &= 0.15\\
> \mathbb P(A\cap C) &= 0.1\\
> \mathbb P(B\cap C) &= 0.06.
> \end{align}
>   The smallest possible value of $P(A^\complement\cap B^\complement\cap C^\complement)$ is:
>
> $(A)\ 0.31$
>
> $(B)\ 0.25$
>
> $(C)\ 0$
>
> $(D)\ 0.26$

\begin{align}
P(A^\complement\cap B^\complement\cap C^\complement)=1&-P(A\cup B\cup C)\\
=1&-P(A)-P(B)-P(C)\\
+&P(A\cap B)+P(B\cap C)+P(C\cap A)-P(A\cap B\cap C)\\
=1&-0.5-0.3-0.2+0.15+0.1+0.06-P(A\cap B\cap C)\\
=0&.31-P(A\cap B\cap C)
\end{align}

Now I am stuck. Can someone guide me to the right answer $(B)$ given in my book?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is great. 
In the last part, Note the fact that the probability of the intersection of A, B and C is less or equal than that of A and B. Similarly B,C or C,A are same. 
In your problem to minimize the probability, maximize P(ABC) with the above fact. Therefore the maximum of P(ABC) is P(BC)=0.06